# How to install web3 on python 3.9.6/3.7.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, blockchain, ethereum, web3py

I tried "pip install web3" , first on 3.7.6 version than changed it to the latest one 3.9.6 it has the same problem.Also fixed the PATH issue of the python folders in control panel but it is showing error.
Type:
python -m venv env
pip install web3

on cmd you might see the same error.

Comment: Welcome! Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Given the info you provided, there's no chance to help you. Please provide precise steps you took and observations you made. Also, ask yourself whether you're reporting a bug (off-topic here) or asking a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to install it on Python3.X, try using pip3 instead of pip.

Comment: It didn't work pip3 showing  errors from bitarray while pip was showing prior to that

Comment: I take it you are using Windows based on the PATH issue you referred to in your original post. I am using Mac OS 10.14.5 and "pip3 install web3" worked fine.  Make sure you are running your pip3 command from the same directory that pip is installed in. On my Windows machine it is C:\Python39\Scripts